# Is this a characterization of commutative $C^{*}$ algebras?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Assume that $A$ is  a  $C^{*}$ algebra with self adjoint elements $A_{sa}$. Assume that for all  $a,b\in A$  we  have $$ab\in A_{sa} \iff  ba \in A_{sa}$$

> Is  $A$ necessarily a  commutative  algebra?

This question is in line of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687407/is-this-a-characterization-of-commutative-c-algebras)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. I will show that any two positive elements of $A$ commute. Since every element is a linear combination of positive elements, this suffices.

Say $a$ and $b$ are positive. Then $a^{1/2}ba^{1/2} \in A_{sa}$, so by hypothesis $ba^{1/2}a^{1/2} = ba \in A_{sa}$. That is, $ba = (ba)^* = a^*b^* = ab$. QED

Comment: Isn't it quicker to observe that any element is a linear combination of (two) self-adjoint ones?

Comment: @ChrisHeunen: I guess positivity is needed to take the square root that makes the proof work. (Notice that OP's assumption is not that self-adjoint elements commute but that $ab$ is self-adjoint iff $ba$ is.)

Comment: Ah, thanks Rasmus, I had indeed wrongly read the assumption as saying that self-adjoints commute.